# Azure web service URL issue

Tags: wcf, rest, azure

I wrote a simple webget service , added this code at web.config..

Then in order to access it i had to type this  http://127.0.0.1/service1.svc/data?value=4

I searched all the config files but couldnt find how to get rid of service1.svc part..

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webby">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceWebRole1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint
          address="/"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="WCFServiceWebRole1.IService1"
          behaviorConfiguration="webby"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Azure, you'll most likely be hosting on IIS.

This article: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/hosting-a-wcf-rest-service-on-iis.aspx explains nicely how to use ASP.NET routing to re-route requests for `Service1.svc` to your service.

Comment: microsoft made it too complicated!

Comment: Now _there_ I agree. The WCF Web API (in CTP) does make this somewhat tidier, though.